# Material design animation

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I am developing an app that will have a very similar interface to [this](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/268236/screenshots/1640866/alarm_material_ui.gif) , my question is, all that animation is from material design, but do i have to program all that stuff or android have anitmation libraries for material design that do that?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the design stuff and animations are only available in android 5.0 and above only, like the `FAB button` and `reveal effect`.

> **2 options**

**Either write the code for animations and layout yourself for pre 5.0 devices**

or

**Use libraries that do the same thing like fab button and reveal effect etc**

There are a lot of open source libraries that you can use in your project for e.g [FAB button](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton), [arc animation](https://github.com/asyl/ArcAnimator) etc.. to support devices before 5.0 Also then you don't forget to read there licence.

> So, in short you will get small components from here and there like
>   reveal effect, arc animation, fab etc use them to achieve the effect.

Comment: You can have FAB. List of what you can not have: [link](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#CheckVersion)